# python 3: Adding .csv column sums in to dictionaries with header keys

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary, sum

I have a .csv file laid out like this:

name1 name2 name3
value1 value2 value3
value4 value5 value6
value7 value8 value9

I need to find a way in Python3 to create a dictionary where the keys are the head names (name1, name2, name3) and the values are the sum of all the values underneath eg. name1 : (value1 + value4 + value7).

So far I've come up with:

```
def sumColumns(columnfile):  
    import csv  
    with open(columnfile) as csvfile:  
        rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)  
        output = {}  
        head = next(rdr)  
        total = 0  
        for column in head:  
            for row in rdr:  
                total += int(row[head.index(column)])  
            output[column] = total  
            total = 0  
        return output
```

I end up returning a dictionary with correct headers but something is going wrong with the sum that I can't pinpoint. One column gets summed and the rest are 0.

Comment: I think your problem is that `rdr` is an iterator. That means you can't re-iterate through it for each of the three times `for row in rdr:` is called - only the first. I'll post a solution in a sec.

Comment: Also just a suggestion that you could initialize the "total" variable to 0 at the start of the outer for-loop and eliminate the repetition of that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not my prettiest piece of code. But here it is. Basically, just store all the information in a list of lists, then iterate over it from there.

```
def sumColumns1(columnfile):
    import csv
    with open(columnfile) as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        names = next(r)
        Int = lambda x: 0 if x=='' else int(x)
        sums  = reduce(lambda x,y: [ Int(a)+Int(b) for a,b in zip(x,y) ], r)
        return dict(zip(names,sums))
```

In an expanded form (or one that doesn't have `reduce` - before someone complains):

```
def sumColumns1(columnfile):
    import csv
    with open(columnfile) as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        names = next(r)
        sums = [ 0 for _ in names ]
        for line in r:
            for i in range(len(sums)):
                sums[i] += int(0 if line[i]=='' else line[i])
        return dict(zip(names,sums))
```

Gives me the correct output. Hopefully someone comes up with something more pythonic.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it's not for my file. I've now found that there's a stipulation here, in that an empty column has to be accounted for (can't convert an empty string to an integer), but it has to be put in the dictionary anyway ie. "": 0. No matter where I try to put a check to pass the ValueError, the sum gets screwed up such that the first row is the only thing put in to the sum for the other columns.

Comment: OK, so you have an extra empty column on your csv? Or do you mean that not all columns have the same height?

Comment: Yeah, I must have missed it. It's the first column and has to be in the dictionary regardless, so the first key would be "" and its value would be 0.

Comment: Edited. This should also fix the problem of variable length columns - should that ever come up.